# In R arima model with known parameter

Tags: r, model, time-series

I want to define coefficient of `arima` model.

For example

```
arima(2,0,2) => ar(2) -> (0.1,0.5) & ma(2) -> (0.2,0.4)
```

How to fit arima model to dataset with user defined parameter in R?

Answer (score 0):

The `fixed` argument in the `arima()` function is designed to do exactly this.

```
fit <- arima(x, order=c(2,0,2), fixed=c(0.1,0.5,0.2,0.4),
  transform.pars=FALSE, include.mean=FALSE)
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/timeseries.html

They have a section on ARIMA models.